# Problems running frequent bash commands in Java HTTP Server

Tags: java, bash, aws-cli, processbuilder, httpserver

I implemented a simple HTTP Server that once calling an endpoint, it will retrieve a text file from S3 and returns it. Unfortunately, when the requests are high, like 100 times per second, it goes to unstable state and can't respond to HTTP requests and they go to timeout. For accessing the S3, I'm run a bash command (which one command takes 2s to execute), so one thought I have is maybe the frequent bash commands and pipes is not efficient. And to add, we are running the code in kubernetes in case it might also cause resource restrictions, etc.

What is the problem? Is it the frequent pipes, HTTP Server API, etc? How to address it?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class FileRetriever implements Runnable {
    HttpServer server;
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder;

    public FileRetriever() {
        processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(serverPort), 0);
            server.createContext("/getfile", new GetFileHandler());
            server.setExecutor(null);
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("HttpServer ERROR", e);
        }
    }

    class GetFileHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
            // parse request
            // http://localhost:9003/getfile?id=xxxxx
            String response = "";
            URI requestedUri = he.getRequestURI();
            String query = requestedUri.getRawQuery();

            String pair[] = query.split("=");
            String id="";
            if (pair[0].equals("id")) {
                id = pair[1];
                try {
                    String command = "aws --endpoint-url="+S3server+" s3 cp s3://file-store/"+id+"/files/"+id+".txt -";
                    processBuilder.command("sh", "-c", command+" ; true");
                    Process process = processBuilder.start();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    BufferedReader readerErrors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response+=line+"\n";
                    }
                    if(response.trim().equals("")) {
                            response="Not Found";
                            he.sendResponseHeaders(404, response.length());
                    }
                    else {
                        logger.info("Received file successfully: " + id);
                        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    response = "ERROR in GetFileHandler.";
                }
            OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there anything that stops you from using the AWS Java SDK to just download the data directly and pass it on as a response?

Comment: Not really. In the early days, I couldn't find many examples on the SDK side how to do it. I would be happy if you can help with converting this code to the Java SDK code.

Comment: @Maurice does it help with latency as well? I have the conversion question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66462064

Comment: It might, the way you're currently doing it seems to be creating a subprocess, calling the AWS CLI and reading that output stream as a file. You could just download the object into memory and serve it from there. Alternatively you might want to look into pre-signed URLs, which you could send to your clients and let them download the data directly from S3. This might save on data transfer costs and your service can be simpler.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that will be a lot of changes on our clients! Btw, this is a cloudian S3. How to get the pre-signed URLs?!

Comment: Apparently through the [regular API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html), if [this website](https://linuxtut.com/en/804dd2c89316ef7b8d57/) is to be believed.