# How to translate my AWS CLI commands to AWS Java API code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I have a piece of code that is called frequently in a HTTP Server. I get the responses on pipes and play with the output String. But apparently using it as AWS CLI pipes as bash scripts may not be very efficient.

What would be the AWS JAVA API equivalent of hese commands? How to convert them? And does it improve efficiency, access latency, etc?

```
public void run() {
    String command = "aws --endpoint-url=" + S3server + " s3 cp s3://file-store/" + id + "/files/" + id + ".txt -";
    processBuilder.command("sh", "-c", command + " ; true");
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    //String command2 = "aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-ourserver.mystore.mycompany.net s3api head-object --bucket file-store --key FILES/3762/files/mytext.scc  --query 'ContentLength'";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader readerErrors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response += line + "\n";
    }
    //...send the response back via HTTP 
    OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.toString().getBytes());
    os.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your goal?  The `aws configure` commands should only need to be done one time unless the access and secret keys are being passed to you (and I'd question the security of that).  After that you can use the [AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html) for things like downloading from S3.  But again, this isn't too terrible depending on how often it's called and the amount of work you want to put into it.

Comment: @stdunbar Sorry, yes. I removed the initialize part which is a one-time thing. The rest can be called up to 100 times per second as a part of HTTP endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

A super simple read from S3 in the V2 Java SDK would look something like:

```
Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
String bucketName = "file-store";

S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
```

...

```
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                                         .bucket(bucketName)
                                         .key(id + "/files/" + id + ".txt")
                                         .build();
OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toOutputStream(outputStream));
os.close();
```

This downloads a file from S3 and writes the bytes directly to the output stream in the HTTP response.  If you're doing this super frequently then the `S3Client` should be created outside of where you're doing the read (i.e. a constructor) and reused.

Now, is this faster than what you're showing?  I strongly expect that it will be but I don't have a way of testing it at the load you're running.

One other option might be to create a [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that a client would request and then they could download the file directly from S3 and not go through your server.  I'm not sure if that would work for your use case.

**EDIT**
I'd strongly encourage you to dig into the [AWS Java SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) and, for your use case, the [S3 Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html).  But until that time, below is a simple program to get a file and two different ways to get the content length.  This one uses local credentials - your use case may be different.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.ResponseTransformer;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.NoSuchKeyException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class DownloadObjectV2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        String bucketName = "the-bucket-name";
        String fileObjKeyName = "file.txt";
        String fileName = "/tmp/file.txt";

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("profile-name"))
                    .build();

            // get meta data about the object without downloading it
            HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest = HeadObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(fileObjKeyName)
                    .build();
            HeadObjectResponse headObjectResponse = s3.headObject(headObjectRequest);
            System.out.println("object is " + headObjectResponse.contentLength() + " bytes long from head call");

            // get the object, save it to a file
            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(fileObjKeyName)
                    .build();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            GetObjectResponse getObjectResponse = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest, ResponseTransformer.toOutputStream(outputStream));

            // meta data is also available from the GetObjectResponse
            System.out.println("object is " + getObjectResponse.contentLength() + " bytes long from get call");
        }
        catch( NoSuchKeyException nske ) { // bad key name
            System.out.println( "the key does not exist" );
        }
        catch( S3Exception s3e ) { // errors like bad credentials
            System.out.println( "a general s3 exception occurred: ");
            s3e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( SdkClientException sce ) { // other errors
            System.out.println( "a sdk exception occurred: ");
            sce.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "run took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try your code. Btw, why is the S3 access so slow?! It takes 2.5s to just get the header (size of the file). Is it normal?

Comment: If you're trying to use S3 as a file server it's not the fastest in the world.  And if your site is not hosted in AWS (for example an EC2) it's even slower.  If this is a file server type of application you may want to rethink your architecture.  You may find a benefit in a lazy cache or other architecture.  But you'll also benefit by keeping the `S3Client` around too as that maintains the connection to AWS.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah problem is we don't know what to cache in advance, before these requests coming.

Comment: A lazy cache would be something that first checks a local file cache for the file.  If it's there it sends that.  Otherwise, it downloads from S3, saves the file to the local cache, and sends it on.  So the first request is about the same speed as above but the second one eliminates the S3 call.  Of course if the files change on S3 and/or expire now you've got a new problem.

Comment: Got it. Yeah all our requests are apparently new requests.

Comment: Regarding S3 access speed, were you actually measuring the awscli? It's effectively execing an entire Python interpreter, loading the awscli and dependent packages, and then making API calls. That's going to be slow.

Comment: Yes I was doing that. I think I'm almost confident going with Subprocess+ Bash + CLI is slow.

Comment: @stdunbar I added another cli command for getting the object size only. Can you update your answer for that as well?
    `//String command2 = "aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-ourserver.mystore.mycompany.net s3api head-object --bucket file-store --key FILES/3762/files/mytext.scc  --query 'ContentLength'";`

Comment: @TinaJ - take a look at the method [headObject](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#headObject-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.HeadObjectRequest-).  Building the `HeadObjectRequest` is very similar to the `GetObjectRequest` I showed and the `HeadObjectResponse` has the `contentLength()` method.

Comment: @stdunbar Do you know how we can address 404 or 403 error codes? like. object not found, connection problems, etc.?

Comment: @stdunbar My code throws credential error. So, I can't still use the aws cli to set credentials? How can I do it within the code?

Comment: See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html) for credential info - google is your friend on these things.